# Why are my Vue Transitions not working after build?

Tags: vue.js

I have just deployed my first vue app that uses vue transitions and I am noticing that my transitions do not work after I deployed the app.  To also share, this app is built with the vue CLI.  These transitions work fine during development but after I ran the build and deployed the app the "enter" transition is not working but the "leave" transition works.  Below is an example of the code (although I don't think it will be so helpful).  What I am wondering is if there is something that takes place during the build process that would result in the css changing?  I did check the final css file after build and I can still see the classes in the file.  Any help is appreciated!

Example:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
  <transition name="modal">
     //more html
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // methods and stuff...
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dialog {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 20rem);
  top: calc(50% - 10rem);
  /* margin-top: 20%; */
  width: 40rem;
  border: 2px solid #00f6f6;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 94;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 93;
}

.modal-enter-from,
.modal-leave-to {
  opacity: 0%;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.modal-enter-to,
.modal-leave-from {
  opacity: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: Is the element inside appearing/disappearing still?

Comment: Yes the element is still appearing and disappearing as I would have expected.  Its not shown here but there is some "v-if" logic for the element